# starting multiple activities in chain

Tags: android, android-activity

Hello android developers

I have three Activities, which are started in some kind of chain.

Activity A -> has start button,which starts Activity B.

Activity B -> 
cancel button,which returns back to Activity A. 
And capture button,which starts activity C with some data.

Activity C ->
retake button,which returns back to  Activity B
use,which must resume activity A with some data.

My question is which is correct way to start these activities in chain,and how can I maintain flow from Activity C to A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Activity A -> has start button,which starts Activity B.**

Start new Activity like

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent);
```

**Activity B -> cancel button,which returns back to Activity A. And capture button,which starts activity C with some data.**

On cancel button you can simply call `finish()` , and on capture button you can start new activity C .

**Activity C -> retake button,which returns back to Activity B use,which must resume activity A with some data.**

on retake button you can call `finish()` , and if  you want to get some input from Activity A  then you should call `StartActivityForResult(1212)` and Receive that code in `onActivityResult`  make the operation that you want in it and finish()  Activity A when you  done , it will autonetically redirect to Activity C , in Activity C's `onResume()` you can able to retrieve that data value .

Comment: thanks for reply.. I have another button on activity c which should navigate to activity A,with some result.

Comment: hey dhams, but i would create Activity A again.

Comment: I have some inputs to get from user in Act A,and if I start Act A from Act C,it would create Act A again and whatever inputs user have entered before navigation will not remain.

Comment: i see . you question is little tweaky  to understand , anyways   i have edited again

Answer (score 1):

Intents are the best way to move from one activity to other Activity.Code

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
}
```

Comment: how can i move from Activity C to A.

Comment: On Activity B you should use finish() under the startActivityForResult() it will take you to the Activity A.Skipping Activity B.

Answer (score 0):

You can start activity C from Activity B as startActivityForResult(intent,requestCode). While returning back from activity C to B get results implemet onActivityResult.

You can do same workflow for C to A and wise-versa.
Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/android-how-to-manage-start-activity-for-result?answertab=votes#tab-top)